# Restrict audience for SharePoint Framework Solutions

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

Is it possible to restrict the audience for SharePoint Framework solutions? By individual sites or users.

Deploying solutions to the app catalog make them available tenant-wide, but some solutions are intended to be restricted so key sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict it to individual site collections by using the Site Collection app catalog which will ensure that SPFx webparts are only available in that specific site collection

Target audiences is not currently supported as webpart property. So, you cant target webpart like you did with classic webparts

References - [Use the site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog)

[Manage site collection app catalog](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-the-site-collection-app-catalog-928b9b61-a9de-4563-a7d1-6231aa9d4d19)